# Navigation button text shadow does not appear iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have so far updated our app's navigation bar back button item to look in iOS 7 as it was in iOS 6, but I can't get a text shadow to appear in iOS 7.

iOS 7:
[image]

iOS 6:
[image]

(the offset was made larger for testing)

Code:

```
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 80.0f + width_offset, 30.0f)];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_back_btn"]  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 15, 5, 5)];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont defaultFontWithType:kFontBold andSize:12]];
    [backButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [backButton.titleLabel setShadowColor = [UIColor blackColor]];
    [backButton.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f)];
    [backButton addTarget:viewController action:@selector(popBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

I would also like to move the button to the left, but this is much less important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the title shadow color on the `UIButton` itself:

```
[backButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```